# Issue with gnome-connection-manager

Tags: network-manager, connection

I use Ubuntu 14.04 with `gnome-connection-manager`.

Everything worked well, but then `gnome-connection-manager` crashed and now I can't start it. The process is not running and a reboot did not help.

How do I troubleshoot this issue?

P.S. Maybe someone could also tell me where `gnome-connection-manager` saves the connections?

Answer (score 1):

This will not recover your `gnome-connection-manager`, but allow you to manage your connections through the terminal:
You can use `nmcli` instead of your normal connection manager.

The most useful commands are:

- List all configured connections:

  ```
  nmcli con
  ```
- Display the status of all active connections:

  ```
  nmcli con stat
  ```
- Start (`up`) / stop (`down`) a connection by name (`-p` = "pretty", displays status):

  ```
  nmcli -p con up id "My connection's name"
  nmcli con down id "My connection's name"
  ```
- Start (`up`) / stop (`down`) a connection by UUID (`-p` = "pretty", displays status):

  ```
  nmcli -p con up uuid xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
  nmcli con down uuid xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
  ```

  You find out the UUID of your connection by looking at the table outputted by `nmcli con`.